# Reading data from excel merge cells using vb.net

Tags: mysql, excel, vb.net

I'm new to vb.net and I'm creating thesis project in our school. I want to fetch data from my excel file where cells was merge and it keeps on popping conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid. Here's my code that I copied and credits for them:

```
Try
        con.Open()
        workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(fileOpener.SelectedPath + "\ahrmt.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        curbook = 0
        Me.Text = String.Format("{0:F0}%", ((curbook / books) * 100)) + " of records has been imported."

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

        Dim maxrow As Integer = 9
        Dim noRecs, AYear As Integer
        Dim semester, course As String

        Me.lblWait.Visible = True

        '=====================================

        Dim str As String

        str = worksheet.Range("A6").Text

        If str.Contains("FIRST SEMESTER") = True Then
            semester = "First Semester"
        Else
            semester = "Second Semester"
        End If

        Dim exAY = Regex.Replace(worksheet.Cells(6, 1), "\D", "")
        AYear = exAY

        Dim AcadY As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

        For i As Integer = 0 To exAY.Length - 1
            AcadY.Append(exAY(i))

            If i Mod 4 = 3 AndAlso i > 0 AndAlso i < exAY.Length - 1 Then
                AcadY.Append(" - ")
            End If
        Next

        course = "Associate in Hotel and Restaurant Management Technology"

        '=======================================


        '--------to get the total rows
        For x As Integer = 9 To worksheet.Rows.Count
            If worksheet.Cells(x, 2).Value = Nothing Then
                Exit For
            Else
                maxrow += 1
            End If
        Next
        '----------for inserting records

        For i As Integer = 9 To worksheet.Rows.Count
            If worksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = Nothing Then
                Exit For
            Else
                Me.ProgressBar1.Visible = True
                Me.ProgressBar1.Value += 1
                Me.ProgressBar1.Maximum = maxrow - 9
                Me.lblImport.Text = String.Format("{0:F0}%", ((ProgressBar1.Value / ProgressBar1.Maximum) * 100))

                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblsif(IDNo, Status, FName, MName, LName, Gender, YearLevel, Semester, AcadYear, PresCourse) " & _
                    "VALUES('" & worksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & "','" & enrolledStat & "','" & worksheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & "','" & worksheet.Cells(i, 6).Value & "'," & _
                    "'" & worksheet.Cells(i, 4).Value & "','" & worksheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & "','" & worksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & "','" & semester & "','" & AcadY & "','" & course.ToString & "')"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                noRecs += 1
                Me.lblTotalRec.Text = "Importing " + noRecs.ToString + " records from AHRMT Course."
            End If

        Next

        'workbook.Save()
        workbook.Close()
        app.Quit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    Me.ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    Me.lblTotalRec.Text = Nothing
    Me.lblImport.Text = Nothing

    con.Dispose()
    con.Close()

    curbook = 1
    Me.Text = String.Format("{0:F0}%", ((curbook / books) * 100)) + " of records has been imported."
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: u need to put this str = worksheet.Range("A6").Text

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it did'nt work. :(

Comment: can you put all code please

Comment: Sorry. I edited my post.

Comment: Sorry did you trie this: Worksheet.Range("A6").Value.ToString()

Comment: Error again sir. :(

Comment: And error is on this line Worksheet.Range("A6").Value.ToString() ?. Please write the error message

Comment: Oh, I think you're right sir coz when I commented the  worksheet.Range("A6").Value.ToString, there's no error and I think it's on the line:   Dim exAY = Regex.Replace(worksheet.Cells(6, 1), "\D", "")
        AYear = exAY

Comment: I figured out already sir. Thanks for the help, much appreciated. :-) God bless.

Comment: I glad i can help :)